# Profile mini-profiler steps across multiple methods, assemblies

Tags: mvc-mini-profiler

I've recently discover mini-profiler and I love it. Unfortunately I'm using EF 5 so I can't use the EF profile element but it's still very useful.

My question is; can I profile a across multiple methods to produce a rolled up step say across by business layer and across the entire repository.

Comment: You might want to try using the new [MiniProfiler.EF5](https://www.nuget.org/packages/MiniProfiler.EF5/) or [MiniProfiler.EF6](https://www.nuget.org/packages/MiniProfiler.EF6/) nugets.

Answer (score 0):

A single `MiniProfiler.Step` profiles everything that happens within the `using` section enclosing the Step. This includes calls to methods in other methods and assemblies. So there is no reason why this should not be able to work.